# Eliminar etiqueta [slq]

Tags: soporte

Propongo se elimine la etiqueta [slq](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slq) la cual esta ligada a dos preguntas y evidentemente la etiqueta correcta a emplear es [sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

Comment: si las editas y la eliminas, se va solita al final del dia...

Comment: ok @gbianchi, eso hare